# Cumsum with conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, cumsum

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:3,each = 3*5), 
             year = rep(rep(1981:1983, each = 5), times = 3), 
             week = rep(rep(20:24, times = 3), times = 3),
             cumsum.val = runif(min  = -2, max = 4, 5*3*3))
```

The data contains `3 locations` X `3 years` X `5 weeks` and a value called `cumsum.val`. For each location and year, I want to find the weeks where `cumsum.val > 1`. Then, if two weeks where `cumsum.val > 1` occur consecutively select the fist week. An example

```
  test <- df[df$loc.id == 1 & df$year == 1981,]
  test$cumsum.test <- test$cumsum.val > 1 # weeks where cumsum.val > 1
  head(test)
    loc.id year   week cumsum.val cumsum.test
 1      1 1981   20 -0.2745349       FALSE
 2      1 1981   21  2.7298308        TRUE
 3      1 1981   22  0.4538615       FALSE
 4      1 1981   23  3.2981044        TRUE
 5      1 1981   24  3.6428037        TRUE
```

Now select the first week where TRUE occurs twice consecutively which in the above case is week `23` (since both week `23` and `24` are `TRUE`).

How can I implement this for the `df`. It could be the case that there is no consecutive occurrence of two weeks where `cumusm.val > 1`. In this case, simple select the first week where `cumsum.val > 1`

Comment: Try `inx <- rev(c(FALSE, diff(rev(test$cumsum.test)) == 0)); test[inx, ]`.

Comment: This works. How do I implement this for the entire `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` based solution can solved the problem. Please notice that `cumsum.test` has been calculated as `numeric` so that `default` value of `lag` and `lead` can used other than `0/1`.

```
df %>% mutate(cumsum.test = as.numeric(cumsum.val>1)) %>%
  group_by(loc.id, year) %>%
  mutate(SelctCond = ifelse(cumsum.test == 1 & 
                       cumsum.test == lead(cumsum.test, default = -1L) &
                       cumsum.test != lag(cumsum.test, default = -1L), TRUE , FALSE )) %>%
  filter(SelctCond) %>%
  select(-SelctCond)
# # Groups: loc.id, year [6]
# loc.id  year  week cumsum.val cumsum.test
# <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1      1  1981    23       3.30        1.00
# 2      1  1982    21       1.17        1.00
# 3      1  1983    22       2.07        1.00
# 4      2  1982    20       3.34        1.00
# 5      2  1983    20       2.25        1.00
# 6      3  1981    20       3.78        1.00
```

Comment: Quick question: what does `-1L` mean in your solution

Comment: @Crop89 I have added comments. `0` and `1` corresponds to `FALSE` and `TRUE` in your case. Now for the very first row `lag` is not available hence that should not be consider as matching value. I have used `default` for `lead/lag` as `-1L` so that it will not match a TRUE/FALSE condition.

Comment: @Crop89 I hope result should be matching to your expectation in the data provided by you. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:3,each = 3*5), 
                 year = rep(rep(1981:1983, each = 5), times = 3), 
                 week = rep(rep(20:24, times = 3), times = 3),
                 cumsum.val = runif(min  = -2, max = 4, 5*3*3))

View(df)
b <- unique(df$loc.id)
data <- data.frame()
for(i in seq_along(b)){
  check=0
  for(j in 1:length(df$loc.id)){
    if(df$cumsum.val[j]>1 && df$loc.id[j]==b[i]){
      check=check+1
    }
    else if(df$loc.id[j]==b[i]){
      check=0
    }
    if(check>=2){
      data1 <- data.frame(week1=df$week[j-1],idd=df$loc.id[j])
      data <- rbind(data,data1)
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a `data.table` approach:

```
require(data.table) # load package
setDT(df) # Convert to data.table
df[, cumsum.test := cumsum.val > 1] # create new variable

# Find consecutive values, check they are indeed cumsum.val > 1, and return the first row of them:
df[c(diff(cumsum.test), NA) == 0 & cumsum.test == TRUE, .SD[1, ]]
```